# iterating over list in list; python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I have a simple problem. I'm new to python and programming so I think i miss something.

The variable "account_info" is assigned earlier and is a list of lists with 4 elements each. The variable current is a user input value, which (should) appear as the first element of the lists in the list account_info.
I want to iterate over the lists in the list and compare if the first element is equal to "current".
This is the code:

```
    for i in account_info:
        if current == account_info[i][0]:
            email = account_info[i][1]
            additional = account_info[i][2]
            pw = account_info[i][3]
    print(email)
```

I get an error in pycharm, when running that code. It seems that I can't iterate over the lists like that, can please someone explain and show a different solution?

Thank you

Comment: The `i` in `for i in account_info` is an element of `account_info`, not an index.

Answer (score 0):

As [@ForceBru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354477/forcebru) commented, your issue is due to how `for` loops in Python work. The value you get from the loop is not an index into the iterable object you're looping on, rather, it's a value from the iterable. That makes your indexing with it later almost certainly wrong (though in certain contexts it might make sense, if you have a list that contains indexes into itself).

In your case, you probably want to do something more like this:

```
for account in accounts_info:
    if current == account[0]:    # note, only the inner indexing is needed
        email = account[1]
        additional = account[2]
        pw = account[3]
```

Since you're expecting the inner lists to contain four values, you could even unpack the `account` values that you get from iterating directly into the inner variables. Though this would happen unconditionally, so it might not do what you want. Here's what that would look like, with the `print` call you were doing after the loop instead moved inside the conditional (so you only print the one email address that corresponds to the value in `current`):

```
for account_id, email, additional, pw in account_info:  # unpack unconditionally
    if account_id == current:                           # use the convenient name here
        print(email)                                    # print only in the conditional
```

In the rare case where you really do need to iterate over indexes, you can use the `range` type, which behaves like a sequence of integers (starting at zero by default). So you could replace your loop with this version and the body would work as you had intended (though this is less idiomatic Python than the previous versions).

```
for i in range(len(accounts_info)):
```

If you need *both* the index and the current value, you can use the `enumerate` function, which yields 2-tuples of index and value as you iterate over it. This is often handy when you need to reassign values in a list some times:

```
for i, account in enumerate(accounts_info):
    if account[0] == current:
        accounts_info[i] = new_value            # replace the whole account entry
```